# Share authentication cookie/membership provider between two sites - second site never authenticates

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on

I have two ASP.NET 4.0 sites on Win2008R2 IIS7, e.g. demo1.site.domain.com and demo2.site.domain.com, and I want to have single sign on. I have searched around and have configured the web.config of both sites like so

```
<machineKey validationKey="ABCDEFG" decryptionKey="HIJKLMN" validation="SHA1" />

<roleManager defaultProvider="RoleName">
  <providers>
    <add name="RoleName" type="Assembly.RoleProvider, Assembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>

<membership defaultProvider="MembershipName">
  <providers>
    <add name="MembershipName" type="Assembly.MembershipProvider, Assembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms 
    loginUrl="http://demo1.site.domain.com/login.aspx" 
    name=".ASPXAUTH"
    domain="domain.com"
    protection="All"  
    path="/"        
  />
</authentication>

<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

In other words the machine key is the same on both web sites and the membership/role providers exist in the assembly of the first site and is used by the second.

The problem I've got is that it doesn't work. I have used fiddler to see what is happening and the auth cookie is never sent to the second site so it always redirects to the login page.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks,
Nik

Comment: Is the second site under the same domain as the first?  If not, the cookies will not be sent.

Comment: i've edited the domain. They are both under the same domain (i've deliberately changed the actual name). They are on the same server and their bindings are

demo1.site.domain.com
demo2.site.domain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are setting the wrong domain in your authentication configuration - it should be "domain.com" (this may be a typo, but worth checking).

You may want to take a look at the following blog about sharing cookies across sub domains:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/article.php/c19417/Sharing-Cookies-Across-Domains.htm

Comment: It was a typo, I have edited the post to show how it really is.

Comment: From reading the above link I think this may be the bit you are missing "Notice the period before the domain name, this is very important. RFC 2109 specifies that the Domain setting on cookies must have two periods." so it should be .domain.com

Comment: Yes, the extra dot before the domain has fixed it. Thank you both and I am sorry I can't vote up as I am new to the site but you have helped a lot.